# Sign data with Ed25519 algorithm

Tags: php, cryptography, ed25519

I want to sign some data with algorithm Ed25519.

Example of private key: `Y2E3YjYwYzRjMDRjMjk1ZDQ5ZTQzM2RlMTdjZjVkNGE0NGFjYzJmM2IzOWExNWZhMjViNGE4ZWJiZDBiMDVkYTIwNGU4MWE3ZWZmMTQ0NGE2ZmM2NjExNzRmNTY4M2I0YmYyMTk5YTkyY2UzOWRkZjdmMzhkNTFjYTNmM2Q3ZDU=`

But I don't know how.

I was trying with `openssl_sign`, but found that is not supporting `Ed25519`.

My php version is 7.4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a modern crypto library for PHP called [Sodium](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php).
The extension is bundled with PHP 7.2.0. [Make sure it's enabled.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sodium.installation.php)
It has the [`sodium_crypto_sign_detached`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sodium-crypto-sign-detached.php) function, which uses Ed25519.

```
$private_key = '...';
$binary_private_key = hex2bin(base64_decode($private_key));
$message = "Hello!";
$signature = sodium_crypto_sign_detached($message, $binary_private_key);

echo bin2hex($signature);
```